# Netty: Start client after server has bootstraped, why another thread is needed?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, netty

I want to start both TCP echo server and client in one app, client after server.

*What I do is:* 
Start a client in a `ChannelFutureListener` returned by `server.bind().sync()` like this:

```
public void runClientAndServer() {
    server.run().addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
        // client.run();                        //(1) this doesn't work!
        new Thread(()->client.run()).start();   //(2) this works!
    });
}
```

and `server.run()` is like this:

```
public ChannelFuture run() {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    //doing channel config stuff
    return b.bind(6666).sync();
}
```

and `client.run()` is like this:

```
public void run() {
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    //do some config stuff
    f = b.connect(host, port).sync(); //wait till connected to server
}
```

*What happens is:*
In the statement (2) that works just fine; While in the statement (1), the client sent message, that can be observed in Wireshark, and the server replies TCP `ACK` segment, but no `channelRead()` method in server side `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` is invoked, nor any attempt to write message to socket can be observed, like this capture:
[wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nxNX.png)

I guess there must be something wrong with Netty threads, but I just cannot figure out

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an example based on the newest netty version (4.1.16.Final) and the code you posted. This works fine without an extra thread maybe you did something wrong initializing your server or client.

```
private static final NioEventLoopGroup EVENT_LOOP_GROUP = new NioEventLoopGroup();

private static ChannelFuture runServer() throws Exception {
    return new ServerBootstrap()
            .group(EVENT_LOOP_GROUP)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("S - Channel connected: " + channel);

                    channel.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("S - read: " + msg.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .bind(6666).sync();
}

private static void runClient() throws Exception {
    new Bootstrap()
        .group(EVENT_LOOP_GROUP)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

            @Override
            protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("C - Initilized client");

                channel.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>() {

                    @Override
                    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        super.channelActive(ctx);
                        System.out.println("C - write: Hey this is a test message enjoy!");
                        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Hey this is a test message enjoy!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception { }
                });
            }
        })
        .connect("localhost", 6666).sync();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    runServer().addListener(future -> {
        runClient();
    });
}
```

That's what the output should look like:

```
C - Initilized client
C - write: Hey this is a test message enjoy!
S - Channel connected: [id: 0x1d676489, L:/127.0.0.1:6666 - R:/127.0.0.1:5079]
S - read: Hey this is a test message enjoy!
```

I also tried this example with a single threaded eventloopgroup which also worked fine but throw me an [BlockingOperationException](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/BlockingOperationException.html) which did not affect the functionality of the program. If this code should work fine you should probably check your code and try to orientate your code on this example (Please don't create inline ChannelHandler for your real project like I did in this example).